# Get the siblings content Jquery

Tags: jquery, siblings

Below is my code, my goal is when the user click the `<a>` I want to alert the content on class='sibling_3' which is 'Hello'.

```
<td class="sibling_1">
    <a href="#">Click Me</a>
</td>
<td class="sibling_2"></td>
<td class="sibling_3">
    <p class="par">Hello</p>
</td>
```

I've tried doing the code below, but it is giving me an undefined error.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.par').html());
});
```

Comment: try `alert($(this).closest('.par').first().html());` or `alert($(this).closest('tr').closest('.par').first().html());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest('td').siblings().find('.par').html());
});
```

Explanation:

```
$(this)          // Get the current link clicked
.closest('td')   // Go to the closest parent td
.siblings()      // Get the siblings of td
.find('.par')    // find the element with .par class
.html()          // Get its content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.par').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().next().next().find('.par').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents('table').find('.par').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content you want to alert is in a class (or id) defined tag, you can do as simply as:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($('.par').html());
});
```

If not and it is in the last sibling, defined or not, the code would be

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents().get(0).siblings(':last').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with shorter one:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.par').html());
});
```

[**Find a Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mt6Bb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($('.par').text()); // Simple way 
    alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.par').html()); // Find through parent
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/34/)